# Calculating the position and the tag of an memory address in the cache

Tags: caching, memory, tags

I want to know if I have solved this problem about direct mapped cache correctly. I need to calculate the position of the block in cache and find its tag.

Given that the CACHE has 1024 BLOCK's and there are 64 bytes per BLOCK, in which position of the CACHE will the address 5C892D0(hex) be stored?

The address 5C892D0 in binary code is:

```
101 1100 1000 1001 0010 1101 0000.
```

As there are 512 bits in every block I know that the rightmost 9 bits (2^9 = 512) is the position in the MAIN MEMORY and the previous 10 bits (2^10=1024) is the position in the CACHE. The remaining bits form the TAG.

So the block position in the CACHE of this address is `0001001001` or the 73rd BLOCK in CACHE, and the TAG is `10111001`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your computation

> Because there is 512 bits in every block i know that the rightest 9 bits 
>   (2^9 = 512)

Blocks are 64 bytes. The lowest bits are for the offset that indicates the byte position within the block and only 6 bits are required. You considered the number of bits (512=64x8), but addresses are *byte* addresses and it is incorrect.

You are right the 10 next bits are the index that selects a block among 1024 in a direct map cache.

And the tag is formed by the remaining bits

Hence offset= 01 0000

index=1001001011=587

Tag=0101 1100 1000